# Integration of $\int_{0}^{1} x^{a}(1-x)^{-1}\log (x) dx $

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I need to compute the following integral for $a>-1$,

$$\int_{0}^{1} x^{a}(1-x)^{-1}\log (x) dx $$

My attempt:

By change of variable $x=1+t$:

\begin{align*}
I &= \int_{0}^{1} x^{a}(1-x)^{-1}\log (x) dx= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1+t)^a}{t} \log(1+t) dt \\
&= \sum_1^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}  \int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1+t)^a t^n}{t}dt=\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}  \int_{0}^{1} (1+t)^a t^{n-1}dt
\end{align*}

Comment: Where do you get the series $(-1)^n/n$ from?

Comment: The last integration is a beta function.

Comment: the integrations limit should be a bit different. Is a solution involving the first derivative of digamma function good enough?

Comment: I think I need to solve further

Comment: According to Mathematica this integral equals $-\zeta(2,1+a)=-\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1+a)^2}$. I don't see directly how to go there, so I leave this as a comment.

Comment: Looks like you replaced log with a taylor expansion of log at a fixed point. That is not correct.

Comment: Ok, I did not see the $t^n$ factor. Not very clear solution.

Comment: How about expanding $(1-x)^{-1}$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding $(1-x)^{-1}$:
$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} x^{a}(1-x)^{-1}\log x\,dx&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^1x^{n+a}\log x\,dx\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Biggl(\frac{x^{n+a+1}}{n+a+1}\,\log x-\frac{x^{n+a+1}}{(n+a+1)^2}\,\Biggr|_0^1\Biggr)\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+a+1)^2}.
\end{align}$$
Since $a>-1$ (or otherwise the integral would not converge), we have $n+a+1\ne0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Where the sum is equal to $\psi^{(1)} (a + 1)$, where $\psi^{(1)}(x)$ is the polygamma function of order one.

Answer (score 2):

As you note, put $x=1-t$
 , $dx=-dt$
 $$\int_{0}^{1}x^{a}\left(1-x\right)^{-1}\log\left(x\right)dx=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{1}\left(1-t\right)^{a}t^{n-1}dt=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{B\left(a+1,n\right)}{n}$$
 where $B\left(a,b\right)$
  is Beta function. If $a$
  is an integer, can be rewritten as$$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{B\left(a+1,n\right)}{n}=\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}-\sum_{n=1}^{a}\frac{1}{n^{2}}.$$ You can find a proof of this fact here [partial sum of Basel problem related to series involving Beta function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55602/partial-sum-of-basel-problem-related-to-series-involving-beta-function).

Comment: where does the sum come from and why does log disappear?

Comment: @mathreadler Taylor series.

Comment: But it is expanded on just one point. If it was a taylor series it should involve $t$ but it doesn't.

Comment: @mathreadler Look inside the integral, there is $t^{n}$. It came from the Taylor series.

Comment: Why the downvote? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, notice that the integral is the derivative with regard to *a* of $\displaystyle\int_0^1x^a(1-x)^b~dx$, which evaluates to $B\big(a+1,b+1\big)$. But since $\Gamma(0)$ is undefined, we'll have to ultimately evaluate the expression by taking its limit as $b\to-1$. However, that limit is nothing more than minus the derivative of $\psi_0(t)$ at $t=2$, namely $-\psi_1(2)=1-\zeta(2)$.